# Grails database is not persist

Tags: mysql, grails

Grails database is not persist after server restart,in my data source file i have following code.
please check where is i am missing.

**EDIT:**

```
   dataSource {
   pooled = true
   driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   username = "admin"
   password = "admin"
  }
 hibernate {
      cache.use_second_level_cache = true
      cache.use_query_cache = false
      cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
  }
 // environment specific settings
   environments {
      development {
           dataSource {
           dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-      8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
        pooled = true
        properties {
           maxActive = -1
           minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
           timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
           numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
           testOnBorrow=true
           testWhileIdle=true
           testOnReturn=true
           validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        }
    }
    hibernate {
        show_sql = false
     }
               }
          test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
        pooled = true
        properties {
           maxActive = -1
           minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
           timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
           numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
           testOnBorrow=true
           testWhileIdle=true
           testOnReturn=true
           validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        }
    }
    hibernate {
        show_sql = false
    }
}
production {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
        pooled = true
        properties {
           maxActive = -1
           minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
           timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
           numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
           testOnBorrow=true
           testWhileIdle=true
           testOnReturn=true
           validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        }
    }
}
}
```

but when i restart server then hole database is drop.any suggestion please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your full DataSource.groovy file?

Comment: @ Sérgio Michels i have updated my question.

Comment: Do you have any config files under .grails dir ?

Comment: yes i have Config.groovy file

Comment: have you verified you're actually saving data?  Also, do you clear anything out in your Bootstrap.groovy file?